# nodemonをインストールできない: Error: EACCESS: permission denied

Tags: node.js

nodemonをinstallできません。どのようにしたらインストールできるようになるのでしょうか?

ちなみにnpmのversionは5.6.0です。

```
hattoriorunoMBP:~ hattoriakitsugu$ npm install nodemon -g
npm WARN checkPermissons Missing write access to /Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! path /Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCESS: permission denied, access '/Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCESS: permission denied, access '/Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCESS: permission denied, access \'/Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCESS',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm/_logs\2018-05-20T00_03_54_549Z-debug.log
```

[image: エラーログ]

### 追記

さらに、sudoコマンドを使ってもできませんでした。

```
hattoriorunoMBP:~ hattoriakitsugu$ sudo npm install nodemon -g
Password:
/Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/bin/nodemon -> /Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js

> nodemon@1.17.4 postinstall /Users/hattoriakitsugu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

+ nodemon@1.17.4
updated 1 package in 7.455s
```

[image: sudoを使った場合のログ]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらの質問ですが、インストールする際に使ったコマンドの内容とインストールする際に出たエラーの内容は見えるのですが、どのような環境にインストールしようとなさっているのかが分かりません。おそらく macOS かと思いますが、詳しいバージョン等は質問者さんにしか分からないため、本文に追記して頂ければと思います。質問文下の「編集」から追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 可能であれば、npm のバージョンと、npm をどのようにインストールしたかの情報も追記して頂ければ嬉しいです。特に、nvm は使っていらっしゃいますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。質問を編集したのでよろしければもう一度回答してください。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。追記の内容を見る限り `sudo install -g nodemon` で nodemon がインストールできているように見えるのですが、何か動かないコマンド等がありましたか？

Comment: 必須ではないのですが、ググラビリティのため、可能であればスクリーンショットではなくてコピー＆ペーストでログを貼って頂けると助かります。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/127012

Answer (score 1):

permission error や EACCESS が出ているので、問題自体は npm モジュールが保存されることになるディレクトリやファイルにアクセスできない、というエラーです。よってエラー・メッセージにもあるとおり、とりあえずのところは `sudo` をつけて管理者権限で実行すればエラーが出ない可能性が高いです。つまり `sudo npm install ～` ということです。

---

ただし私個人的には、これだと根本的な解決にはなっていないと思います。というのも今回パーミッションのエラーが出ているのは自分のホームディレクトリ直下なので、できれば `sudo` 無しでアクセスできた方が望ましそうだからです。nodemon 特有の問題というよりか、npm をインストールした際の設定由来の問題だと思います。

今後も `sudo` 無しでインストールできる方が望ましい場合、npm の公式ドキュメント ["How to Prevent Permissions Errors"](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) が参考になります。これによると、以下の選択肢があります。

- 選択肢1: Node Version Manager (nvm) を使って npm を再インストールする
- 選択肢2: npm のデフォルト・ディレクトリを変更する

また macOS の場合、`brew` を使って再インストールする選択肢もあるでしょう。とにかく `~/.npm-global/` 以下のパーミッションを直したいだけなので、手動で `chown` などする方法でも上手くいくかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

と表示されているように、管理者権限でインストールのコマンドを実行してみてください。

```
$ sudo npm install nodemon -g
```